# How to animate breaking model

Tags: animation

This is the reference gif file. How can i achieve this in Blender. The breaking of the parts and disappearing later.

[image: demo gif]

Any suggestion or Help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to use effectors, which are not built into Blender: there are many addons online like "Blender effectors" that could do that, maybe, but if you want to be sure try Animation Nodes.
It's a bit more complicated but very customizable.
In any case, you need to fragment the object beforehand (there are addons that do this too) and animate a plain effector (the one you see in the picture) over the object, apply a rigid body simulation to all pieces a make the effector trigger it when it get close to each piece. Also create a plane on the ground with a rigid body simulation, and set it as an obstacle.

Now you have the statue breaking into pieces and falling onto the ground: At this point animate the material color of the pieces from gray to the color you want, and finally to white, and make the effector trigger it as well when it gets close. Also animate the scale so that when they fall on the ground they shrink and disappear.

I don't know what your skill level is, and I was a bit vague, so if you have troubles working with effectors watch some tutorials on you specific effectors addon, since they may operate in different ways (also, make sure they support rigid body and color simulations before downloading them)